# Converting .doc/docx in to Html

Tags: html, css, ms-word, converters

I know that Word have option to save the document into web page, but what is produce as result doesn't suit my needs.

I want my document to be save as web page with separate folder, which include images and .css files. But the Word only include the images not the css file.

How can I achieve this with Word or some other tool (need to be free)?

Comment: I really would not recommend using Word for creating web pages.

Comment: There's a bunch of free What You see Is What You Get editors: https://www.google.nl/#q=free+wysiwyg+html+editor  Try one of them

Comment: The tool need to be for non-developer or some convertor which can easily convert doc to html+css

Answer (score 0):

Given that Java is your preferred language, you could try docx4j [disclaimer: I manage it].

See the [CreateHtml](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/CreateHtml.java) sample.

Note: docx4j supports docx only (as opposed to legacy binary .doc; those can be converted using LibreOffice).